# Import existing test cases in new Katalon project

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm fairly new to Katalon Studio, and google-fu + documentation research was not successful.

A company has a large test automation Katalon project developed without a plan for a long time. Now, I was tasked with the re-organization of the project into smaller projects.

I've created a blank project, now I would like to import existing test cases into it. How can I do so? I was hoping to find an "*import existing test case*" option somewhere.

<sub>Note: Importing existing Test Suites is an option as well, as long as they bring everything they need with the import. Homebrewed scriptable solutions are welcome.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is currently possible. There's no such option.

I believe your best course of action would be to import (or just plain copy) the existing project and then edit it.

Comment: The existing project is really big, and would have multiple smaller projects spawned from it. More importantly, git organization would change, as well as a lot of stuff. It's sad that the system doesn't allow import existing test cases. I'll do my best.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no context-menu available option from Katalon Studio<sup>1</sup>, an hack-ish work-around can be exploited: open two instances of Katalon Studio and copy/paste or Drag'nDrop content from the project to migrate from the first instance to a brand new emtpy project in the second instance.

**Pro**: the new project has a different UUID, whereas with the approach from [Mate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080224/import-existing-test-cases-in-new-katalon-project#) you would end up with two projects with the same UUID. Moreover, this is scriptable and automatable.

**Con:** I am getting a few error messages when doing this operation regarding metadata copy, which I need to investigate.

However, there is a workaround to the error messages: copying content in the /Test Cases, /Test Suites folders and then doing a Refresh of the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) makes the copied content available in the new project.

The operation is not smooth, as some CIs, e.g. the Profiles, are not available in all the menus, e.g. the Profiles dropdown in the top right corner, but they can be worked out later on.

---

<sup>1) as of now, version 7.3</sup>